# Format number to currency in locale pt-br

Tags: javascript

I've looked for some examples here, but without success

I want to take my string and convert it into monetary value

```
const text = 25990
const replace = text.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
```

The return is as follows `R$ 25.990,00`

But I want the return to be `R$ 259,90`

Comment: Why don't you set it as a string `text = '259,90;`?

Comment: comes from the api, and what comes from the api is that value

Comment: you can format it to fit your needs, right? You need to add comma before last 2 digits. You can do it with `const last2digits = stringObject.slice(-2)` and you will get `90`. Then you can create  new format with `cons newFormat  = tstringObject.slice(0, stringObject.length - 2) + ',' + last2digits;`

Comment: In the sample code you provided, `text` is not a `String`. It's a `Number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to *assume* that your `text` variable holds the amount in **centavos** (1 **real** = 100 **centavos**).

Then you simply have to divide by 100 to display the correct value in **reals**:

```
const centavos = 25990
const reals = centavos / 100;
const formatted = reals.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
```